# Can i merge my custom model and pretrained model in yolov9

Tags: dataset, object-detection, yolov8

My custom model is  trained to detect objects across 4 distinct classes, and my objective is to integrate it with a pre-trained YOLOv9 model. This merging process is intended to result in a new, enhanced model that can effectively identify objects belonging to a set of 84 classes.

In my efforts, I have been focused on the process of loading both my custom model and the pre-trained YOLOv9 model.